# 90-100% Disk usage after command window popped up (unprompted), some commands/processes showed and disappeared

Tags: command-line, windows-10, virus

It happened pretty quickly and I didn't notice exactly what happened in that command window (MS-DOS style). I ran Norton Power Eraser, Malwarebytes and have Norton Anti-Virus on all the time. When it happened, I was on some unfamiliar but not-dangerous web-site (uBlock on).

How can I figure out what happened?

Comment: Install the WPT (part of the Win10 SDK: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk), run WPRUI.exe, select **First Level**, **CPU usage**, **DiskIO**, **FileIO** and click to start. Now capture 1 minute of the DiskIO after opening cmd.exe. After 1 minute click on **Save** inside WPRUI. Zip the large ETL file into zip/RAR file, upload the zip (OneDrive, dropbox, google drive) and post the share link here.

Comment: @magic The activity disk subsided to normal (zero without load) after a while, but I am still (slightly) worried about what actually happened with that command window popping up out of the blue and clearly running some commands/closing done on its own. Recording the current vitals won't help, I assume (as of now CPU hovers between 5 and 10 without any load which might be unusual).

Comment: WPRUI records in a loop and internally deletes the old data. So run it for a while until you see the issue again. Now go to WPRUI and save the trace

Comment: @magic The only observable "issue" at the moment is 3-8% idle CPU (i5-4570T) usage. Is that at all a matter of concern? Any guesses as to what could have caused that command window pop-up without looking at current trace data?

Comment: no, without looking at the trace I can't see anything. In the trace I see all running processes and here I could see a cmd/conhost.exe processes.

Comment: any update on the issue?

Comment: @magic Idle Disk usage is back to 0-1% with very occasional, very short spikes to 20-40% (very slow drive) and idle CPU is under 5%. This is not a cause for my concern, unless there is a "dangerous" explanation of that command window pop-up that is consistent with current stats (I did do some adjustments inbetween, but nothing drastic and Norton Power Eraser/Malwarebytes didn't found anything).

Comment: but wit hthe trace I can see the command line of the CMD. Run WPRUI, click on start and forget it (minimize the Window of WPRUI). When you see the CMD Windows popping up, wait until it is gone, restore WPRUI and click on save to store the trace. Zip and share this trace

Comment: maybe it is this tool that pops up shortly: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/usoclient-exe-windows-10

Comment: @magic Thanks for the effort. That pop-up was a one-time, out of the blue, not upon boot-up thing and now everything is back to "normal". If it happens again, I'll record, but unless there is a theory as to what happened, I won't.